# How can hide item like calendar , chat and calls for some users in britix24 menu?

Tags: bitrix

Hello guys I am new in bitrix24 and i want to know how to hide some items (calendar , chat and calls) in menu from users to see?

someone can help me please

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drag the menu items below the hidden lines (MORE), and then `CONFIGURE MENU -> Set my menu for everyone`.

For further customization of modules, you can disable CRM, Extranet, Time management, Meetings, and Lists in the SETTINGS menu.

That is the limit of what you can do in CLOUD; even more is available in ON-PREM admin panel.